# Perforce: How to find if a user has modified a file or not?

Tags: perforce

I wish to find if a user has modified a file in any of the perforce branches.
Is there a simple command to find it?

input: UserName and FileName 
output: changelist or no changelist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p4 changes -u {user} //.../{filename}
```

Comment: Does not address the "branch" issue, but still works well :-)

Comment: If you get tagged output, and assuming you have a fairly late-model server, you can infer the branch info from the 'path' attribute of each change. (Tagged output is what you get with 'p4 -ztag' or any of the Perforce scripting APIs.)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a combination of [p4 filelog](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/filelog.html) and grep.

```
p4 filelog {filename} | grep {username}
```

Comment: But then, this command will have to be run across all the branches.

Comment: Are all of your branches mapped in your .p4client view?  If so your filename could be .../*filename.ext